# ActionScript error #1053 - Illegal override of allowInsecureDomain in _MonkeyContacts_mx_managers_SystemManager (FlexMonkey code generation example)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, flash-builder

I'm following along the MonkeyContactsCodeGenExample guide and when I run the ant target for test-with-launcher, I get a popup saying:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of allowInsecureDomain in _MonkeyContacts_mx_managers_SystemManager.
```

This is followed by:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _MonkeyContacts_mx_managers_SystemManager is not defined.
```

These popups are from the debug flash player - the normal flash player would silently supress these errors.

It seems that these sorts of errors occur when different files or swc components are compiled under different SDKs.  If so, what parts would I need to recompile in this situation?

I checked out the flex project sources and have rebuilt them under SDK 3.4, and I also got the project sources for fluint and have recompiled those already.  The newly compiled fluint.swc was then copied to the lib directories of the MonkeyFluintAirTestRunner and MonkeyTestLauncher projects and then everything was re-built, but I still get this error with the MonkeyContacts example.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this myself today.  I just needed to recompile the MonkeyAgent.SWF.

As per a note on the FlexMonkey site, I used the Easy2BuildMonkeyAgent project to do this.  I didn't look into why they recommended this, but it worked for me.

Beware, I ran into a problem compiling this because I use the standard 3.4 SDK that was installed separate from Flex Builder.  The the standard 3.4 SDK, the automation.swc file (and others) aren't there, so I had to grab copies from the FlexBuilder 3.0 SDK folder into the 3.4.

Comment: Thanks - I was able to build the MonkeyAgent.swf file.  Unfortunately, I'm at a loss for what to do with it.  Can you elaborate more on what to do with this file?  How do you hook it up with the ant tasks?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MonkeyContacts example you're referencing, but I'd say the MonkeyAgent.swf probably needs to be put into the bin-debug folder (or wherever the compiled output of the example app is going to).

Comment: R.e. Flex 3.4 automation libs - see here: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk  - there's a separate download for the automation and data visualization stuff.  If the 3.0 stuff works for you that's good, but in case you wanted the 3.4 stuff...

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't notice the separate downloads before.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to copy the corresponding files from locale/en_US: automation_agent_rb.swc, automation_rb.swc